# How to call a DLL built by LabVIEW with C++

Tags: c++, dll, call, labview

nice to meet you!
this is my first post to stacoverflow.
I am studying C++ and LabVIEW for my own education.

LabVIEW is graphical design programming environment and it can build DLL from LabVIEW code.
"Creating a DLL from LabVIEW code"
https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-15556

I built a simple DLL and trying to call it from C++ code.
we can sum A and B by the DLL.
First, i made a source code as follows.

```html
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\sum_dll.dll"));
  if(hDLL == NULL){
  cout << "error" << endl;
 }
 
 FARPROC lpIO = GetProcAddress(HMODULE(hDLL),"Sum_dll");

 typedef int (*FUNC)(int a, int b);

 FUNC myFunc;
 myFunc = FUNC(lpIO);

 int myValue = myFunc(2,32);

 cout << myValue << endl;

 FreeLibrary(hDLL);
 return 0;
}


**************************** DLL header file ****************************

#include "extcode.h"
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/*!
 * Sum_dll
 */
int32_t __cdecl Sum_dll(int32_t A, int32_t B);

MgErr __cdecl LVDLLStatus(char *errStr, int errStrLen, void *module);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif

#pragma pack(pop)

*****************************************************************************
```

it worked fine and the result of "myValue" was 34　(2+32).
it was ok.

next, i changed dll configuration and C++ code as foolows.

```html
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int (*FUNC)(int, int,int *);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\sum_dll.dll"));
  if(hDLL == NULL){
  cout << "error" << endl;
 }
 
 FARPROC lpIO = GetProcAddress(HMODULE(hDLL),"Sum_dll");
 
 FUNC myFunc;
 myFunc = FUNC(lpIO);

 
 cout << myFunc(2,3,0) << endl;

 //cout << "myValue = " << myValue << endl;

 FreeLibrary(hDLL);
 return 0;
}



**************************** DLL header file ****************************

#include "extcode.h"
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/*!
 * Sum_dll
 */
void __cdecl Sum_dll(int32_t A, int32_t B, int32_t *C);

MgErr __cdecl LVDLLStatus(char *errStr, int errStrLen, void *module);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif

#pragma pack(pop)

*****************************************************************************
```

"myValue" returned "0".
it was not expexted result and it should return 5 (2+3).

I think my code has a problem, but i could not find out what cause this.
Please comment if you have any advice.

Thank you!

Comment: You've commented out `myValue` in the code you have.  So how could it return 0?

Comment: What does the third argument in your second version of `myFunc` denote?  Is that supposed to be the sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the third argument to `myFunc` denotes the sum:

The function signatures do not match.  The `myFunc` returns void, but your function pointer typedef says it returns an int.  The behavior is undefined when you do this (I'm surprised the program didn't crash).

`typedef void (*FUNC)(int32_t, int32_t, int32_t*);`

Also, you should match *exactly* the types the exported DLL function expects.  In the typedef, you say `int`, but the function takes `int32_t`.

Given the fixes above, the other issues:

1) The call should pass the address of `myValue`

2) The DLL function returns void, so it makes no sense to use it in `cout`.

```
myFunc(2,3,&myValue);
cout << "myValue = " << myValue << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your comment.

I changed my C++ source as follows.
There was no crash and returned correct value.

i believe i shoud learn C++ pointer and variable type.
Thank you so much!!

```html
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint> //shoud be called to use int32_t
using namespace std;

//define the type of function
typedef void (*FUNC)(int32_t, int32_t,int32_t *);


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{// Loads the specified module into the address space of the calling process.
 HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\sum_dll.dll"));
  if(hDLL == NULL){
  cout << "error" << endl; // error check
 }
 
 //Retrieves the address of an exported function or variable from the specified dynamic-link library (DLL).
 FARPROC lpIO = GetProcAddress(HMODULE(hDLL),"Sum_dll");
 
 //define type
 FUNC myFunc;
 myFunc = FUNC(lpIO);

 //define returned variable
 int32_t myValue;

 //call function
 myFunc(2,3,&myValue);

 cout << myValue << endl;

 FreeLibrary(hDLL);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It did not work until I included the .lib file in the project properties->linker->Input->Delay Loaded Dlls